# Hard Code a system value?

Tags: powershell, inventory-software

I work for a Tech company, and when we sell computers we also include a sticker with an inventory number, for easy reference in our database. My question is as follows:

Is there a way (I am sure there is) to hard code a variable to the system that can be called later? Such as when using:

```
wmic bios get serialnumber
```

OR

```
gwmi win32_bios | fl SerialNumber
```

I was thinking of a way to define a variable somewhere here, or possibly within the Registry? And then using Powershell to retrieve the data from the registry if we ever need to reference the Inventory # and the sticker has been removed.

Are there other options to achieve this sort of functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You can generally assign an asset tag in the BIOS, depending on versions. I can't give a specific answer without knowing the BIOS type. If you're selling Dell or I believe Lenovo systems, you can assign tags quite easily.

This article details how to use Windows-Shell-Setup to enter various information and details about the system seller in the Windows Environment itself. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff715801.aspx

Comment: I've done some research per your comment. They are dell machines, when I try Wmic SystemEnclosure get SMBiosAssetTag, it is not defined. However, I've read that it is a read only attribute and cannot be written to without Vendor Specific Software.
Was this the attribute that you were referring to, or is there another location that I can look at?

Comment: I know that CCTK was the old name of the program, looks like the current version is this: http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/enterprise-client/w/wiki/7431.dell-client-command-suite

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the software build, why not add a .bat file or .exe to the system path when building.

If you create a file called serialnumber.bat or write an exe called serialnumber.exe then you can call it and return the variable.

Perhaps if you use .bat you can use it to define the variable at runtime